# Copy data from multiple workbooks to a another workbook

Tags: python, pandas

With the code below, I am trying to copy the data from existing files `filenames_array` which are loaded in `my_path` in the master file (path for master file is `my_path1`).

Important aspect here is that January data should be pasted on `Jandata` sheet, February data on `Febdata` and so on.

Code runs without any error but master file has no changes at all.

```py
filenames_array = [
    "PB orders Jan",
    "PB orders Feb",
    "PB orders Mar",
    "PB orders Apr",
    "PB orders May",
    "PB orders Jun",
    "PB orders Jul",
    "PB orders Aug",
    "PB orders Sep",
    "PB orders Oct",
    "PB orders Nov",
    "PB orders Dec",
]

masterfile_sheetname_array = [
    "Jandata",
    "Febdata" "Mardata",
    "Aprdata",
    "Maydata",
    "Jundata",
    "Juldata",
    "Augdata",
    "Sepdata",
    "Octdata",
    "Novdata",
    "Decdata",
]

# Retrieve the list of filenames (without extension) in my_path
files_no_ext = [
    os.path.splitext(f)[0] for f in os.listdir(my_path) if os.path.isfile(f)
]

for filename in files_no_ext:  # Iterate over the list
    if filename in filenames_array:  # If the filename is in the list
        # Create the 'month' DataFrame
        month = pd.read_excel(
            os.path.join(my_path, filename), sheet_name="Raw data ", engine="pyxlsb"
        )
        with pd.ExcelWriter(
            os.path.join(my_path1, "Master.xlsx"),
            mode="a",
            if_sheet_exists="replace",
            engine="openpyxl",
        ) as writer:
            month.to_excel(
                writer,
                sheet_name=masterfile_sheetname_array[
                    filenames_array.index(filename)
                ],  # Since the lists share the same indeces, use the filename to retrieve the name of the sheet
                engine="openpyxl",
                index=False,
            )
```

Comment: Hi, have you checked that `files_no_ext` is not empty?

Comment: If I have files in `my_path` then it should not be empty no?